# skip deleting records when a child record is found

Tags: plsql

i have a pl/sql procedure to modify/delete records based on a checkbox selection in my Apex application:

```
delete from s_objectif_operation where id_operation=:p124_id_operation;
for a in (select distinct id from s_objectif
         where id in (
         SELECT trim(regexp_substr(:P124_S_OBJECTIF, '[^:]+', 1, LEVEL)) str
         FROM dual
         CONNECT BY instr(:P124_S_OBJECTIF, ':', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
        ))
loop
    insert into s_objectif_operation 
    (id_s_objectif, id_operation)
    values 
    (a.id, :p124_id_operation);
end loop;
```

for every modification, this procedure deletes all the records and insert the correct ones back so i had to remove the "cascade on delete" option the foreign key constraint to suspend any child record removal but now the procedure is not working.
maybe "raise an exception" can work?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Would exception help? Can't tell. Sample data might help.

Comment: Why are you deleting just to reinsert. Instead of the delete/insert cycle just use the [Merge](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9017.htm#SQLRF01606)  statement to update existing rows and insert the new data. That will avoid your FK exception when child rows exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to delete all the records and re-inserting only the checked ones. That is a brute force approach and it works but it does not capture the real user action.
As an alternative you can just delete/insert the changes. To do that, create an additional page item P124_S_OBJECTIF_OLD and set it to the value P124_S_OBJECTIF with a computation after header (or any pre-rendering processing point after P124_S_OBJECTIF has been initialized). In your pl/sql code use `APEX_STRING.SPLIT` to process the checkbox values and the `MULTISET` operator to decide which values have been touched.

Then your pl/sql process code could look like this.

```
DECLARE
  l_objectif_old apex_t_varchar2;
  l_objectif_new apex_t_varchar2;
  l_objectifs_added apex_t_varchar2;
  l_objectifs_removed apex_t_varchar2;
BEGIN
  l_objectif_old := apex_string.split(:P124_S_OBJECTIF_OLD,':');
  l_objectif_new := apex_string.split(:P124_S_OBJECTIF,':');
  l_objectifs_added := l_objectif_new MULTISET EXCEPT l_objectif_old;
  l_objectifs_removed := l_objectif_old MULTISET EXCEPT l_objectif_new;
  -- add new 
  FOR i IN 1 .. l_objectifs_added.COUNT LOOP
    INSERT INTO s_objectif_operation (id_s_objectif, id_operation)
      VALUES (l_objectifs_added(i), :P124_ID_OPERATION);  
  END LOOP;
  -- delete old 
  FOR i IN 1 .. l_objectifs_removed.COUNT LOOP
    BEGIN
      DELETE FROM s_objectif_operation 
       WHERE id = l_objectifs_removed(i);
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
      -- this will fire if there are child records. Add your own code.
      NULL;
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Note that you might have to tweak the insert and delete statement to match your data structure.

Comment: your suggestion (and solution) worked well, thanks ^^

Comment: how can i print a message to the user in ```EXCEPTION``` to tell him the item can't be added or removed?

Comment: You _could_ set a page item (say P124_ERROR_MSG) with that message and then, in "error message" display that message using syntax. &P124_ERROR_MSG. . However, it makes more sense to create a validation that checks if the user has checked any records witch child records and fail the validation if that is the case.